# Htaccess tag being replaced by the directive tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I've seen some questions with [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess) tags being replaced by [mod-rewrite](/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite) tags. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889881/htaccess-file-causing-chrome-to-lose-session-data) for example, edited by @Charles.

What's the policy about that kind of tag reselection? Will then all [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess) tags be replaced with the corresponding directive tag and what happens when the file has different directives, like [mod-alias](/questions/tagged/mod-alias), [redirect](/questions/tagged/redirect), etc. A lot of tags, no doubt, making harder to find the subject.

Maybe that's the policy, but I don't think it's coherent in any way. Htaccess files can't be separated from Apache directives. I agree with adding the directive(s) tag(s), but highly disagree with removing the most important tag: [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess). Searches will have to be more precise, which is too much to ask to somebody who doesn't know exactly what he wants. That's the reason for searching in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh good, I've been meaning to bring this up, but haven't been able to find a non-ranty way.

You've probably seen a lot of these edits lately.  I've been hanging around the new question list in [php](/questions/tagged/php) lately on a bit of a wager.  Along the way I've been trying to reduce the sheer volume of *suck* caused by the influx of newbies.  A lot of newbies have *astoundingly* bad tagging skill.  I hate bad tagging.  *Hate*.  So I fix it.

None of the retagged questions are actually about the .htaccess file *itself*, but the actual directives inside, as you've noted.  In *all* of these cases, the directives are *almost exclusively* those from mod_rewrite.... maybe with an occasional `Redirect` ([mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html)) thrown in for fun.

Because they're *really* mod_rewrite questions, it's more important to have [mod-rewrite](/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite) in there than [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess).  It doesn't matter where the configuration directives are *in these questions*, so the more narrowly-targeted tag is going to be a better match so that people that care about mod_rewrite can help.

This is almost but not quite a general case scenario.  Questions that concern mod_rewrite should be tagged as such.  Questions that *actually* concern .htaccess should be tagged as such.  The fact that mod_rewrite directives can be placed in .htaccess doesn't mean that .htaccess needs to be on *every single question*.

Comment: You have a valid point and appreciate your answer. Hope this question helps to make it clear to those that have the same concern. I really didn't see it that way because I thought it would affect somehow searching, but now I'm not so sure as the relevant parameter in any search is the subject, not the tags. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I've always despised the [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess) tag, simply because it can encompass many different modules within Apache - **it's ambiguous**. I agree with the retag. Your question is specific to the Rewrite module in Apache. You can't be an expert on "htaccess" because **htaccess, alone, is only a configuration file**. You have to know the pieces of the modules you're configuring, and *those* are the things you can be an expert in. This tag honestly makes no sense, it should be blacklisted after a mass clean-up to *appropriately* tag all the questions under it, most of which *should* go to [mod-rewrite](/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite).

If your problem inside the htaccess file encompasses more than one Apache module, you should tag your question with each module that it covers, such as [mod-rewrite](/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite) and [mod-alias](/questions/tagged/mod-alias).

Comment: I think your answer is equally valid and clear but unfortunately can't upvote nor accept twice. Thank you very much for your answer and your time.

Comment: @FarFromGenius You can surely up-vote two, or more answers given for the same question, even if you asked the question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: He didn't have enough reputation.

Comment: @kiamlaluno and animuson I just saw the comment and yes, I did not have the rep. Now I have it and upvoted. Thanks again.